# SmartGWT TreeGrid field filter with SelectItem

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, treegrid

I am using SmartGwt 3.0, GWT 2.4.0 in IE9.

I have a smartgwt treeGrid in which i customize a field filter to be a `SelectItem` as follows:

```
...
TreeGridField field = new TreeGridField();

SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
selectItem .setShowTitle(false);

LinkedHashMap<String, String> lmapKeyLabel = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

for(...) {
      lmapStatusLabel.put(key, "<b>"+label+"</b>");
}

selectItem.setValueMap(lmapKeyLabel);
field.setFilterEditorType(selectItem);
treeGrid.refreshFields();
...
```

The presented values on the `SelectItem` are the **keys** and not the labels.
The same happens with a `ComboBoxItem`.

Has this happenned to someone? Am i doing something wrong?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
mif